# Implementing routing with parameter

Tags: angular, url, angular2-routing

I have a relatively complete Angular 4 web application and the routing never use parameters:

```
domain.com/questions/
=> than you choose your questions in a html select
```

I need to implement routing with parameter like this :

```
domain.com/questions/23/
```

To go directly on a specific questions

what's the best way to implement 'route params subscription' in my 23 component without repeating myself ?

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use questions/:id in your routing module. Then in you component use this

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

public questionId:any;

ngOnInit(){
   this.router.params.subscribe(res => {
        questionId = res['id'];
    })
}
```